# Freeboard - MIT license vs Pricing reality

Tags: licensing

I am confused with this product (freeboard) licensing.

On their website they specifies pricing:
https://freeboard.io/#pricing

While on GitHub it says MIT License, ok for  Commercial use
https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard

Is it ok to download and use locally a business?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can take the MIT licensed code from Github and use it for a business (or any other purpose for that matter).

You will of course have to pay for hosting, the time to configure it and install it, make sure somebody is monitoring it for security issues, find a way to upgrade it when a new version is released, and a whole load of other tasks. Given all that, you may find it more cost-effective to let somebody else (possibly freeboard.io) manage it all for you - which is the service they offer.